# Is there a way to stop absolute positioned divs from disappearing on small screens?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm not really sure how to explain this so here is a picture:
[Window To Small http://vsave.org/my/user_folders/Ian33_159/image.jpg](http://vsave.org/my/user_folders/Ian33_159/image.jpg)

As you can see in the picture, as the screen shrinks, the picture moves out of view because I use the code:

```
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -450px;
    width: 900px;
```

since it is subtracting 450px it moves into the left of your screen where you can't see it anymore.

Here is the code for my body tag:

```
    body {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
min-width:1000px; /* suppose you want minimun width of 1000px */
width: auto !important;  /* Firefox will set width as auto */
width:1000px;             /* As IE ignores !important it will set width as 1000px;*/
    }
```

If you need more information just let me know.
Thanks

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve? What behavior do you expect?

Comment: And what is the intended behavior?  How would you like it to fit a `900px` div into a `600px` screen?  Should the box shrink when the window gets below 900?

Comment: This might be nippy, but on a 600px screen there is just no way to show 900px container.

Comment: @FlorianRachor Nope not nippy at all, i just wanted it to force the browser to scroll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a `min-width` on the parent element (or `body`) and that will make it so that the window will have horizontal scroll instead of running off the page.

Note that `min-width` is IE 7+

Comment: I tried this but it still moves off of the page, ill add my body code

Comment: @Ian34 put `position: relative;` on the body and see if that helps.

Comment: Wow, for years ive been trying to fix this and its just been those two words. Thank you so much @Ktash

Answer (score 0):

You could use media queries to adapt to the smaller screen size:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
 #container {
  position: static;
  /* Or */
  width: 450px;
  margin-left: -225px;
}
}
```